# Scrape stock exchange data from html5 figure or website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to automatically scrape some stock exchange data in 1 or 5 minute ticks from the website stooq.com. I've tried to get it using `BeautifulSoup` from `bs4`, but can neither find it in the tables of the website, nor can I manage to get the underlying data of the html5 chart.

This is the link to the website containing the html5 chart:
`dax_link = 'https://stooq.com/q/a2/?s=^dax&i=1&t=l&a=lg&z=500&ft=201808141221&l=0&d=1&ch=0&f=0&lt=57&r=0&o=1'`

I've tried the following using beautifulsoup:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

stooq_dax = ('https://stooq.com/q/a2/?s=^dax&i=1&t=l&a=lg'
             '&z=500&ft=201808141221&l=0&d=1&ch=0&f=0&lt=57&r=0&o=1')
reqstdax = requests.get(stooq_dax)
stdax = reqstdax.content
soupstdax = bs(stdax)
tbls_dax = soupstdax.table
df = pd.read_html(str(tbls_dax))
```

But none of the 31 dataframes contains any useful data.

I also tried finding some specific values in the website, like for example

```
soupstdax.find_all(text=re.compile('12368'))
```

which is the "open" value at the time `2018-08-14,15:24:00`, but none can be found.

I can of course get these values by clicking on the **csv** button in the bottom right corner, but this can't be automatized since the link to the csv-generation is hidden (and I did not manage to reconstruct it).

Is there any way I could get the underlying data of the chart or find the correct link for generating the csv files?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the web-page in Chrome or FireFox you see it making a XHR to:

```
https://stooq.com/q/a2/d/?s=^dax&i=1&l=201808141633
```

You can access this directly to get the data that the page is updated with:

```
20180814,163200,12349.80,12350.10,12348.50,12348.50
20180814,163300,12348.5,12350,12348.1,12349.5
```

Is that the data you want?

**Update**
It looks like the initial data comes from here:

```
https://stooq.com/q/a2/d/?s=^dax&i=1
```

And the 201808141633 is a timestamp (2018/08/14 16:33)

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot! Yes, that is exactly the data that I want. I tried to inspect the website in Firefox, but still was not able to see that, probably because I do not understand much of html/http etc. and thus did not know of XHR until now. How did find out the link? I just inspected the site and found the quite huge `<script>` section but can't get any useful information from this.

Comment: In FireFox right click -> Inspect Element -> Network -> XHR and reload the page. (I'm just trying to find where the 201808141633 comes from it could be dynamic.)

Comment: Ok, thanks alot. This really helped me alot. Using Inspect I also found the XHR from boerse-frankfurt.de for ticks and Intraday ranging with different timestamps, for example [here](http://proxy.boerse-frankfurt.de/cst/BoerseFrankfurt/Share/chart.json?instruments=16830,998032,830,814&period=Intraday) which prints out all data of the day or [here](http://charts.finanzen.net/ChartData.ashx?request=HISTORY+998032;830;814+TICKS+100), printing only a number of sets (100 in this case). This can also be altered to intraday, replacing `TICKS` with `INTRADAY 1`, 5, 60 etc. where 1, 5... is the tick.

Comment: Unluckily these data streams all have a delay of ca. 15 minutes. And I did not manage getting the push data of boerse-frankfurt.de. This is still absolutely awesome and way more than I was hoping for! Thanks alot! Now I have *too many* options out of which I have to chose... ;)